# fs2.Stream[IO, Something] does not return on take(1)

Tags: scala, fs2, cats-effect

I have a function that returns a fs2.Stream of Measurements.

```
import cats.effect._
import fs2._

def apply(sds: SerialPort, interval: Int)(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): Stream[IO, SdsMeasurement] =
  for {
     blocker <- Stream.resource(Blocker[IO])
     stream <- io.readInputStream(IO(sds.getInputStream), 1, blocker)
      .through(SdsStateMachine.collectMeasurements())
  } yield stream
```

Normally it is an infinite Stream, unless I pass it a test flag, in which case it should output one value and halt.

```
val infiniteSource: Stream[IO, SdsMeasurement] = ...
val source = if (isTest) infiniteSource.take(1) else infiniteSource
source.compile.drain
```

The infinite Stream works fine. It gives me all Measurements infinitely. The test Stream indeed gives me only the first measurement, nothing more. The problem I have is that the Stream does not return after this last measurements. It blocks forever. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I think I abstracted the essential code, but for more context, please take a look at my project: https://github.com/jkransen/fijnstof/blob/ZIO/src/main/scala/nl/kransen/fijnstof/Main.scala

Answer (score 0):

The code you've presented here looks fine, I don't think the issue lies within that code. If it blocks, then presumably one of the underlying APIs blocks, for instance it might be the `close` method of the `InputStream`. What I usually do in such situations is to add log statements before and after every function call that might block.